# Batch Time problems when used in echo

Tags: batch-file, time, cmd, echo

I have a problem with my batch program, I want it to show what `time / t` does in a echo line but when I do this

```
@Echo off
Set echotime=time /t
echo (%date%)(%echotime%)
```

Only need XX:XX cause XX:XX:XX,XX Makes it too long for the log file i wanna have for my program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo (%date%)(%time:~0,5%)
```

the `:~0,5`construct takes five chars beginning with char 0 (the first one)